# why my function does not return the desired value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

When I call the function from somewhere else, it does not return the desired value, the problem is that it returns an undefined value before executing the function, it works I have it stored in a service.

login.page.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.auth.getRole());
}
```

auth-admin.service.ts:

**First Attempt**

```
getRole() {
     this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
       if (user) {
         this.afs.firestore.doc(`Core/Usuarios/Admin/${user.uid}`)
         .get()
         .then(userProfileSnapshot => {
           let isAdmin = userProfileSnapshot.data().udbid.role;
           return isAdmin;
         })
       }
     });
   }
```

CONSOLE LOG

> undefined

In my second attempt I put a console message before returning the value, which gave me in my console the desired value but it did it some time after giving me an undefined value, but the function never applied the return.

**Second Attempt**

```
 getRole() {
     this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
       if (user) {
         this.afs.firestore.doc(`Core/Usuarios/Admin/${user.uid}`)
         .get()
         .then(userProfileSnapshot => {
           let isAdmin = userProfileSnapshot.data().udbid.role;
           console.log(isAdmin)
           return isAdmin;
         })
       }
     });
   }
```

CONSOLE LOG:

> undefined
>
> Admin

Comment: I mean.. getRole doesn’t actually return anything. Just return the promise..?

Comment: @MikeOne thank you for your information, although the documentation seemed very technical, however, it was very complete, it helped me to understand certain things, but I found this in the Hispanic community (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110242/como-hacer-correctamente-una-funcion-que-retorne-una-promesa-con-ionic), it helped me a lot, however thank you very much for your prompt responses and your support, I solved my problem by the way, thank you very much seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your getRole function async.

Comment: result: ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}

Comment: thank you, I used promises to solve my problem, thank you very much for your prompt response.